# Why I can't enable frontend editing (TYPO3 Extension frontend_editing) in TYPO3 9.5?

Tags: frontend, typo3, editing

I don't know why but I cannot enable frontend editing in TYPO3 9. I have installed the extension frontend_editing and I see the frontend editing backend module... but there is just no editor.

Look at this:

[image: this is how it looks... there is no editor. i cant do any editing]

In my typoscript I did

```
config.frontend_editing=1
```

and, in my user TSConfig:

```
setup.override.frontend_editing_enable = 1
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds, like you've forgotten to include the static TypoScript template.

[Frontend Editing - Installation - Required steps](https://docs.typo3.org/p/friendsoftypo3/frontend-editing/master/en-us/Installation/Index.html#required-steps):

> Add the static TypoScript template Frontend Editing to the site roots where the features should be activated
>
> [image]

Comment: Hey thx for your answer, but I forgot to tell you. I already had included the static TypoSscript Template :(